# What .net data technology is best enabling user def fields via XML in this project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic-data

I am new to ASP.NET / .net, i have designed the screens and database structure for a side project webapp and ready to start coding it. I needed user defined fields and after much deliberation over the pros and cons of the options i decided to implement them as an XML blob.

Im looking at 3 options for data access:

1) Entity Framework: i havnt found an in on how id go about this with EF

2) Dynamic Data: i could create custom field template that produces label / textbox pairs, but it would be under one column header if i viewed it in a (eg gridview)

3) Coding a DAL / BLL myself, using just sql connections. ObjectDataSources would give enough flexibility in the UI hopefully. (I would split the fields in the BLL here i take it?)

I want to stick with MS tech, rather than NHibernate or such, so this will help with learning for the MCTS cert (also why im not using MVC as i need to know both eventually for it). I also, perhaps wrongly, think in using solution no. 3 i would be gaining the least relevant experience in terms of what employers would want. What do you guys think is a good solution for my newbie skill level here?

### Edit

Once i got into the implementation I decided against using xml blobs, opting instead for spare fields and a meta table.

Comment: Whip up couple of prototypes and see what feels better.

Comment: XML blobs sound like trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to gain a valuable skill employers would want I would definitely code the DAL / BLL yourself.

The WCF Data Services has BLOB support. This [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg465167) from MSDN uses EF but might be a good start.

Also check out this MSDN section on [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)